# Waveshare 13460, GSM HAT doesn't power on

Tags: pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os, gps, hat, gsm

Got this guy [waveshare](https://www.waveshare.com/gsm-gprs-gnss-hat.htm), which stopped powering ON after the first run(which was successful). The power LED is ON, but nothing happens after I press the PWRKEY. I got other identical module which turns on with PWRKEY successfully.
Seems to me that smth is wrong with SIM800 module.

This happened after I pulled GSM HAT from the Raspberry PI, so there is possibility that I might have damaged the PCB, but I didn't do any harsh moves :)

Please advise, maybe FW update may help, or what else can I check?

Thank you!

Comment: you are describing a failed module

Comment: yes, it worked but then failed, need an advise how to repair

Comment: `how to repair a GSM module?` is not a question that relates to the Raspberry Pi ... it is off topic here

Comment: GSM-hat for Raspberry

Comment: Found that there is no voltage on the Pin 39, used as the power key to turn on the Sim868 module. Pin should be pulled-up internally to 3.3V. Does that mean that Sim is dead?